# Why does Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop crash on my system?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've just installed Visual Studio 2012 Express on my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 system.

Unfortunately if I start it I see the UI for about 3 seconds (I can browse the menus), after which I get a *Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop has stopped working* dialog. Before this VS 2010 Express was installed, which has worked fine for 2 years.

Event Viewer shows this:

```
Faulting application name: WDExpress.exe, version: 11.0.51106.1, time stamp: 0x5098b5f8
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.17929, time stamp: 0x4ffa5753
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00371a6a
Faulting process id: 0x141c
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce28d9255639ca
Faulting application path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 660dcaa2-94cc-11e2-9bd2-00241ddeaee6
```

I've tried to reboot several times, a repair install, installing the update 1 from here (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update) and also this on the command line:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe update /force /queue
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe eqi 1
```

Unfortunately it does not help.

I've also tried loading a HelloWorld.csproj with the same result.

Why does it crash?